# Declaring a group of text as a string C++

Tags: c++, string

Im making a hangman game for a school project. The way its set up is, the pictures are pre-designed and called "boards" and as the user makes an incorrect guess the program displays each "board" progressively. But the teacher wants us to declare each board as a constant and thats the part thats getting me.

```
cout << " -------|" << endl;
cout << " |      |" << endl;
cout << " O      |" << endl;
cout << "-|-     |" << endl;
cout << "/ \\     |" << endl;
cout << "      -----" << endl;
```

this is the final "board" but i cant seem to declare the entire piece of code as a constant. And i don't know wether to declare it as a string, char, or what? I've tried closing it all into parenthesis and also using {}. Not sure what to do... please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a string constant, `\n` is a linebreak, and you can concatenate string constants just like that:

```
String board =
    " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    " O      |\n"
    "-|-     |\n"
    "/ \\    |\n"
    "     -----";
```

Comment: This won't work in C++; you can't add the regular string literals together.

Comment: @bames53: Right, was in Java mode, have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

All together:

```
std::string board = " -------|\n |      |\n O      |\n-|-     |\n/ \\    |\n     -----";
```

Using string literal concatenation

```
std::string board =
    " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    " O      |\n"
    "-|-     |\n"
    "/ \\    |\n"
    "     -----";
```

Using raw string literals (A feature of C++11 which not all compilers still in use support)

```
std::string board =
R"( -------|
 |      |
 O      |
-|-     |
/ \\    |
     -----)";
```